# Render a div visible or hidden depend on mouseOver and mouseOut

Tags: javascript, html, css, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have these 9 cards, for each cards when the mouse is over the component I would hide/visible
.

```
``
<div class="cards__food">
    <% @foods.each do |food| %>
      <%= link_to(foods_path) do %>
        <div class="card__food">
          <div class="card__food-img" style="background-image: url(<%= food.image_url %>);"></div>
          <h3><%= food.name.upcase %></h3>
          <div id="hide">
            <p>ORDER</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <% end %>
      <% end %>
  </div>
```

```
#hide {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

- I selected each cards. Each have been assigned to a variable cards.
- To have effect on  i did the same things

Here is my trouble, without forEach i can't use addEventListener.

the console said:

TypeError: cards.addEventListener is not a function

So i used forEach. But when the mouse is over a card only the first card trigger and render visible or hide:

```
          <div id="hide">
            <p>ORDER</p>
          </div>
```

depend on mouseover/mouseout

```
const addOrderToFood = () => {
  const cards = document.querySelectorAll(".card__food");
  const order = document.getElementById('hide');
  if (cards) {
    cards.forEach(card => {
      card.addEventListener("mouseover", (event) => {
        console.log(event)
        order.style.visibility='visible';
      })
      card.addEventListener("mouseout", (event) => {
        console.log(event)
        order.style.visibility='hidden';
      })
    })

  }

}
```

I can't find a issue and I really want to beat this piece of code haha ! :D

Comment: the problem is you are attaching the `eventListner` each time  the `addOrderToFood` method is being called. You don't need to loop through all the cards and attach eventlistner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Plain CSS will do. `hide` selector should not be an id, because it is appearing multiple times on the page.

```
.card__food:hover > .hide {
    visibility: 'visible';
}
.card__food > .hide {
    visibility: 'hidden';
}
```

Comment: So i should remove forEach() ?

Comment: Yes, remove it.

Comment: .card__food > .hide {
  &:hover {
    visibility: 'visible';
  }
}

.card__food > .hide {
    visibility: 'hidden';
}

Comment: if i remove forEach i have this error: TypeError: cards.addEventListener is not a function

Comment: Why are you attaching event listeners for mouseover and mouseout? This is being handled from CSS

Comment: Yes i just realise each cards are a link. So without css with hover should work right ?

Comment: Thank's for your help you make it so simple ! haha